# SSRS End of Support

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, eof

We are wondering when SSRS end of life date is, to plan for migration of the reports we have in SSRS 2013 to a new platform.

I have tried to find the SSRS end of support date in MS product life cycle, but couldn't find it.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/lifecycle/search/1044

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: SSRS is still part of SQL Server 2019, which was released **today**. The support of the version you have lasts as long as the Version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems MS doesn't have plans to end support.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/editorials/ssrs-is-still-around/